# Let $A$ be a non-empty, open set in $\mathbb{R}$. Show that the $\sup(A)$ does not belong to $A$?

Tags: real-analysis, real-numbers

So since the question states that $A$ is a non-empty, open set in $\mathbb{R}$, this implies that every point within set $A$ is an interior point.

In other words, every arbitrary point $p$ within set $A$ adheres to:

$$ \exists\varepsilon>0 \ni N_\varepsilon(p)\subset A$$

Let $$\alpha = \sup(A) $$

Then

$$\forall\varepsilon>0, \alpha + \varepsilon \not\subset A$$

Thus, the $\sup(A)$ can not belong to set $A$ if $A$ is an open set?

Is this enough proof?

Comment: Almost.  Explain why $\alpha + \epsilon \not \subset A$ for all $\epsilon$ is a contradiction.

Comment: Don't confuse $\not\subset$ with $\notin$; you should use the latter.

Answer (score 1):

You have the right idea. It might also happen that $\sup A$ does not exist, if $A$ isn't bounded above. If $A$ is bounded above, then $\alpha = \sup A$ does exist, and it cannot belong to $A$ for the reason you've stated: if $\alpha \in A$ then $\alpha$ would have to be an interior point, but $\alpha + \epsilon$ does not belong to $A$ for any $\epsilon > 0$.

Answer (score 0):

The proof is correct. If  $\sup A=s$ is a number (without considering $\infty$ as a $sup$) , then $s\in \partial A$ but since $A$  is open : $A=\bar {A} -\partial A$.

Answer (score 0):

Almost.  Just explain why the last line is a contradiction.

I'd do it this way (although there are other arguments)

$\forall \epsilon > 0; \alpha + \epsilon/2 \not \in A$. So, as $\alpha + \epsilon/2 \in  N_{\epsilon}(\alpha)$, it follows $ N_{\epsilon}(\alpha) \not \subset A$.  So $\alpha$ is not an interior point of $A$.  So, as $A$ is open, $\alpha \not \in A$.